# What is the distribution of highest order statistics when the random variables follow exponential distribution with mean ?

Tags: expected-value, exponential-distribution, order-statistics

Suppose $X_i \sim \exp(\theta), i = 1, \ldots, n$, iid.
So the pdf is given by $f(x) = \exp(-x/\theta)/\theta, x>0$.
Now I need to find the distribution of maximum of $X_i$ i.e. $X(n)=T$ (say).

So from cdf I got the pdf of $T$ as

$f(t)=n (1 - \exp(-t/\theta)^(n-1) \exp(-t/\theta)/\theta ,t>0$

But now I can not find the ${\cal E}(T)$ and $Var(T)$, I used by parts two time but I can not execute it properly. Will you please help me out

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80475/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3560742/321264